# How to close Context Menu using double tap with modifiers held on

Tags: autohotkey

Description :
by pressing the combination of ( alt + d ) a context menu will popup.
while still holding alt ( modifier key ) i will double tap ( d keys ) so that context menu will close and execute the sub labeled routine.

now my problem the line after `If (A_PriorHotKey = A_ThisHotKey and A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < 400)`
doesnt work ( double tapping )

i tried adding AltGr before executing the sublabeled routine because ive read somewhere that pressing those keys will automatically close the context menu

here's the code

```
; ------------- Context Menu layout / list

Menu, PS_Grouping, Add, Grid, grid_command
Menu, PS_Grouping, Add, Ruler, ruler_command
Menu, PS_Grouping, Add,
Menu, PS_Grouping, Add, Cancel, close_context


; ------------- Hotkeys ( Single / Double Tap )

!g::
If (A_PriorHotKey = A_ThisHotKey and A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < 400)
{
Send, {AltGr down}
send, {AltGr up}
sleep 30
Gosub, grid_command
}
else
Menu, PS_Grouping, Show
return



; ------------Labeled Subroutine

grid_command:
send {ctrl down}{' down}
send {ctrl up}{' up}
return

ruler_command:
send {ctrl down}{l down}
send {ctrl up}{l up}
return

close_context:
return
```

the code posted above is actually working if i press double tap simultaneously ( alt + d ) + ( alt + d ). but this is not what i after
currently the code posted Above do this

main goal :
while still holding alt key modifier after executing `Menu, PS_Grouping, Show` which is single tap ( alt + D ) , double tapping ( d keys ) will close the context menu then execute the labeled subroutine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a hotkey to close the menu for executing a command in that menu.

All you have to do is to click on the menu item (the item "Grid" in this case) or

underline one of the letters in the menu item, adding an ampersand (&) before that letter. When the menu is displayed, you can select that item by pressing the underlined  letter on the keyboard.

```
; ------------- Context Menu layout / list
; Press g or click on the first menu item to execute the subroutine "grid_command"
Menu, PS_Grouping, Add, &Grid, grid_command
Menu, PS_Grouping, Add, Ruler, ruler_command
; Menu, PS_Grouping, Show
return

grid_command:
    MsgBox, grid_command
return

ruler_command:
return

; Press alt+g to show the menu
!g:: Menu, PS_Grouping, Show
```

Comment: hello the reason why i want to execute  the double tapping for quickly executing the command i assigned to it without looking at the menu's and clicking it. for example https://imgur.com/J7g994O i have this assigned to alt + w  ( single tap ) to bring up the context menu it consist of several menu list  but my goal is i just want to quickly create new layer but without looking it so i just quickly press alt + w + w ( double tapping method ). Question is the ampersand pertains to first letter of menu? like if its new layer then i need to press N after the menu shows up

Comment: Pressing only one key (g in this case) is faster than double tapping. Press Escape to close the menu or execute the command `Send {Esc}` by double tapping.

Comment: to add comment above about ampersand i think its counter unintuitive for me like in this scenario / image https://imgur.com/J7g994O after i bringing up the menu i need to press N which is far away from keyboard . but i muscle memory alt + w ( single tap ) in another application its create new layer default for me ( no context menu ) just assigned shortcut .. and i want a new workflow that alt + w consist of menu list then double tapping is old - new method ( creating new layer )

Comment: The ampersand can be added before no matter which letter or number in the menu item.

Comment: let me try it on another context menu , the example code posted above is coincidence that alt + g are the same letter as grid. and this time the context menu  https://imgur.com/J7g994O which was assigned to alt + w . so by adding ampersand to new layer. after pressing alt + w then w , i can execute the new layer command?

Comment: Yes, if you use `Ne&w Layer` as item name.

Comment: oh okay so i need to find and assign ( ampersand ) corresponding letter for the command so i can execute it quickly at context menu. how about in this scenario https://imgur.com/a/SRi8iwH this was assigned to ( alt + f ) i want smart object . to be executed quickly after pressing alt + f then f . so i just need to rename 'Smart Object' into  ' [&F] Smart Object ' so it will be prioritize over the fill command ?

Comment: I would assign another hotkey to that command, Adding [&F] isn't very intuitive and I will have to remember it.

Comment: well , actually the combination ( alt + f + f ) or (alt + g + g ) it acts similar to double tapping quickly. this is really what i after. i already muscle memory  frequent command  i use when the time im still not using context menu the only difference is its now double tapping . single tap alt + f ( is my default smart layer / smart filter ) .. but anyway thank you so much for helping me this already solve my case. have a good day

Comment: Now that you know how it works, use it as it suits you. By the way, you can add the ampersand to a submenu item as well. Then you have to hit two letters or twice a letter after your hotkey to activate that submenu item.